# Extra space on top of website in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a new website design and everything seems to be working on chrome, yet on internet explorer (only the newest version, it seems), there is a ton of white space added on top of the website.

Basically on IE, it almost looks like I had 500px of padding-top. But it displays perfectly on chrome.

The current URL is cspclaw.com

Thanks.

I posted the entire main page HTML here: http://pastebin.com/eDmfuRWK

And the entire main page CSS here: http://pastebin.com/GK3TRtx4

Comment: Just a question, is the JS that handles the image transformations doing anything to their position. I don't see anything in the CSS that would cause the issue.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but a margin-top: -220px will get you there :) The image giving the issue is the /logo.jpg. If you change the height to 1 or something small, you will see that everything else moves up.

Comment: 1 more comment, I was playing around with your rowspans, and it started to move everything correctly.

Comment: Having problems with any version of IE is normal and expected.

Comment: hey, I guess my real problem, is that I know how to debug problems in chrome because I can right-click "inspect element" and then play around with it like you are saying. Is there any way to add this functionality to IE so I can play around with the CSS/HTML within the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an IE bug to me.
It calculates the height of the `<tr>` through the height of the contents of the highest `<td>`, disregarding the `rowspan="2"`.
If you remove the rowspan attribute, you can kind of see why it's doing what it's doing.

The problem for IE is that every single `<td>` in your second row (the row containing the `<div class="fadein">`-cells) has rowspan="2". Remove that, and the page will no longer show that odd margin/padding in IE.
It still doesn't look the same, my guess is more rogue rowspans... :)

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll take a look at it, I wish there was an easy way to fix IE inconsistencies... because it shows up perfectly on Chrome.